# Algorithm for [inclusive/exclusive]_scan in parallel <algorithm> proposal N3554

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, c++14

Proposal [N3554 (A Parallel Algorithms Library)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3554.pdf) for C++14, proposes (among other things), what seem to be parallel versions of the current [`std::partial_sum`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/numeric/partial_sum/), e.g.:

```
template<
    class ExecutionPolicy,
    class InputIterator,
    class OutputIterator,
    class BinaryOperation>
OutputIterator inclusive_scan(
    ExecutionPolicy &&exec,
    InputIterator first,
    InputIterator last,
    OutputIterator result,
    BinaryOperation binary_op);
```

With the explanation

> Effects: For each iterator i in [result,result + (last - first)), performs *i = prefix_sum,
>   where prefix_sum is the result of the corresponding sum init + *iter_0 + *iter_1 + *iter_2 +
>   ... or binary_op(init, binary_op(*iter_0, binary_op(*iter_1, binary_op(*iter_2, ...)))
>   for every iterator iter_j in the range [first,first + (i - result) - 1) ... The order of operands of the sum is unspecified.

---

How could this operation be made parallel? It seems like, almost by definition, each output prefix_sum must be calculated for the immediate next one to be calculated - essentially leading to a serial operation.

---

**Edit** Many thanks to Aasmund Eldhuset for his answer. Personally, I found ["Prefix Sums
and Their Applications" by Guy E. Blelloch](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf) to be very useful.

Comment: Looks like a nice and accessible paper; thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Parallel prefix sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Parallel_algorithm) is a classical distributed programming algorithm, which elegantly uses a reduction followed by a distribution (as illustrated in the article). The key observation is that you can compute *parts* of the partial sums before you know the leading terms.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link!

Comment: @AmiTavory: Glad you enjoyed the read (and I needed to refresh my own memory of it, anyway)!